# How to get rid of Multiple Python installations - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04

I have multiple installations on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS machine and I am looking for assistance to get rid of them and have a simple Python 3.7 installation

```
python --version
Python 2.7.15+

python3 --version
Python 3.6.8

python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

How do I get rid of these and have a single installation on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Machine ?

Please assist

Comment: System packages will likely need at least 2 of those, so it would be ill-advised to remove them. It's better not to worry about them and use a virtualenv for your projects.

Comment: You can use specific version of python with virtual environment.

Comment: so when I use a Virtual Environment, the buildozer, pip etc would not pick the other versions ? and how can I open the IDLE based on the Virtual Environment ?

Comment: That question's more suitable to superuser.com rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can probably get rid of python3.7 without many issues.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Considering that Ubuntu has its own distro-specific site I believe AskUbuntu.com would be a better fit...

Comment: Fully agreed, @GiacomoAlzetta!

Answer (score 2):

You can try what happens if you run:

```
sudo apt-get purge python2 --dry-run
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge python3.6 --dry-run
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge python3.7 --dry-run
```

As result you will see, what system packages are related to that python version.

From the [apt-get manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> **-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act**
>
> No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.  Configuration Item:
>   APT::Get::Simulate. Simulate prints out a series of lines, each one
>   representing an rpm
>       operation: Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square brackets indicate broken packages with an empty set of square brackets
>   meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare).